# In Chef, is there a way to load attributes from a subdirectory?

Tags: chef-infra

Let's say I want to lay out an attributes directory like so

```
cookbooks
|- ...
attributes
|- project-one
|--- foo.rb
|--- blah.rb
|--- bar.rb
|- project-two
|--- bang.rb
```

Is there a way to get chef to find the attributes from the subdirectories listed here? I have a lot of attributes :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately sub directories is not currently supported (for attributes, libraries, recipes, etc). This item is on the roadmap for Chef 12.

Even if you do some crazy Ruby magic, like doing a dir-glob and require relative, those files in subdirectories won't be uploaded to the Chef Server.

If you find the need for that many attribute files, I would suggest re-examining the domain scope for your cookbook. In general, a cookbook should manage a single application or service. If you find yourself having many different features and cases, you may want to try breaking it into smaller cookbooks. I'd be happy to take a look and provide some guidance.

Comment: For anyone finding this answer via Google (like me), this didn't make it into Chef 12, but can be followed here https://github.com/chef/chef-rfc/issues/24

Comment: RFC is AWOL :( must have been deleted ?